# How to get the true dimension of a numpy array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to display a numpy file, then display its correct length, I put my file in folder:

```
import numpy as np
import os
path= "C:\\Users\\user\\Folder"
files= os.listdir(path)
filepath= os.path.join(path, files[0])
file0= np.load(filepath)
print(file0)
print (len(file0))
```

The result is an imbrication of tables, which gives me as length=1 instead of length=8000 :

```
[[ 0.01437869  0.01506449  0.01579909 ...,  0.04166172  0.0417285
   0.04172079]]

1
```

But I need to have is:

```
[ 0.01437869  0.01506449  0.01579909 ...,  0.04166172  0.0417285
   0.04172079]

8000
```

How to resolve this problem please.

Comment: Use `.ravel()` or `np.squeeze()`.

Comment: and have a look at `.shape` instead of `len()`.

Comment: Looks like the true `file0.shape` is (1,8000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
file0= np.load(filepath)[0]
```

Comment: I like this syntax to unpack single item sequences better, but YMMV: `file0, = np.load(filepath)`.